# Accessing static extension function from another class in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, extension-function

Let's say we have the following extension function:

```
class Helper {
  companion object {
    fun Int.plus(value: String) = Integer.valueOf(value).plus(this)
  }
```

}

How can you access the `plus` extension function from the `Helper` class in another class. Is there a way where we can do something like this for instance:

```
class OtherClass {
  fun someMethod() {
    val eight = 7.Helper.Companion.plus("1")
  }
```

}

Answer (score 5):

In your example `Int.plus(value: String)` is a member function of the `Helper.Companion` object (the fact that it is a companion object or that it is inside another class does not matter). This case is described in the [Declaring Extensions as Members](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html#declaring-extensions-as-members) section of the documentation.

In short, to access a function with *two* receivers (an extension receiver of type `Int` and a dispatch receiver of type `Helper.Companion`) you have to have them both in the scope.

This can be achieved in a number of ways:

```
with(Helper.Companion) {
    239.plus("")
}
```

or

```
with(Helper.Companion) {
    with(239) {
        plus("")
    }
}
```

P.S. Putting an extension function into a companion object is very irregular and not idiomatic. I can hardly imagine why you would need that.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer :)

Answer (score 3):

An extension declared like this is a [`member extension function`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html#declaring-extensions-as-members), and is only going to be visible within the `Helper` class. If you need to access it outside of that class, put it in a wider scope, for example, make it a top level function. Alternatively, you could make it a regular function that takes two parameters, if you want to keep it within a class.

---

As an additional hint, you can mark this function an [`operator`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/operator-overloading.html) if you want to use it with the `+` symbol:

```
operator fun Int.plus(value: String) = Integer.valueOf(value) + this

val x = 2 + "25"
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer this